# Multiple Node.js setting on same server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have dev1 and dev2  folder on server

dev1 is working fine,  under dev1 i have file **js/common-path.js** 
in common path i jsyt mention: **dev1.example.com:1337/**
I made changes in dev2  like

> dev2.example.com:8124/

and I have forever module install globally, i also renamed file app.js in nodejs folder of dev2 to dev.js

when i run command for dev1 /nodejs/ forever start app.js
and i jsut run command for dev2 as /nodejs/ node dev.js
 now when i run dev2.example.com it is  sending request to dev1 . i checked obver console.

I also made changes in port number in dev.js

```
 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8124);
```

Any ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean when you access: `dev2.example.com:8124`,`dev1` catch the request?

Try the following:

1. Remove `process.env.PORT`,use `app.set('port',8124)` and try again.
2. Stop dev1,start dev2,and try again.
3. Check your nginx config if you are using it.

Comment: Can u tell me how to check nginx config

Comment: You have't config nginx? nginx config file path always is `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: About how to configure nginx for node.js:https://gist.github.com/joemccann/644282